# Problemas al utilizar condicionales en la generación de una estructura de árbol para devolverlos en mi Laravel 9 api

Tags: laravel, postgresql, postman, laravel-9, tree

Tengo un problema al tratar de generar una estructura de datos tipo árbol en Laravel 9 específicamente al utilizar dos condicionales.

Los pongo en contexto estoy tratando de llenar el árbol con los datos de una tabla (DB postgres) que contiene la información de un plan de cuenta.

Esta aplicación es de tenencia múltiple y comparte la misma base de datos con todos los usuarios, tengo un identificador que se llama company y con este se a quien pertenece el plan de cuentas, el asunto es que quiero tener un plan de cuentas genérico y que solo las cuentas nuevas sean las que pertenezcan a X compañía y asi evitar tener que incluir las mas de 400 cuentas cada vez que se crea un registro.

Entonces lo que trate de hacer fue en mi tabla plan de cuentas dejar el campo company en null para las genéricas y solo agregar el UUID de la compañía cuando este crea una cuenta nueva como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Modelo

```
 public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AccountPlan::class, 'pcNumberAccountId', 'pcNumberAccount')
            ->orderBy('pcNumberAccount' , 'ASC')
            ->where('company', '=', NULL)
            ->orWhere('company', '=', Auth::user()->company)
            ->with(['children']);
    }
```

Mi controlador:

```
$account_plan = AccountPlan::whereNull('pcNumberAccountId')
                ->with(['children'])
                ->orderBy('pcNumberAccount' , 'ASC')
                ->where('company', '=', NULL)
                ->orWhere('company', '=', Auth::user()->company)
                ->get();
```

Cuando hago la consulta solo utilizando el primer where me trae la información completa pero al agregarle el orWhere para obtener también los que pertenecen a la company, falla es mas demora cargando y no muestra ni el error solo sale que el estatus es 500 en el postman.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi sale la petición cuando me trae los datos sin usar el orWhere

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano les agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar